# Moodle php get current user country

Tags: php, get, profile, moodle

How can I get current logged in users country from profile information? I have searched many sites, have found some answers, but I haven't got them working.

I currently have this code, that doesn't do the work:

```
global $user;
        if ($user->country == 'Estonia') {
            redirect($CFG->wwwroot .'/course/view.php?id=15');
        } else {
            redirect($CFG->wwwroot .'/course/');
        }
```

Comment: Try to change `global $user` to `global $USER`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$user->country stores the iso country code

```
SELECT u.country
FROM mdl_user u;
```

You can get the list of country codes from 
`/lang/en/countries.php`

Estonia is 'EE'

So change your code to

```
if ($user->country == 'EE') {
```

If the code is for the current logged in user then you should $USER in capitals.

Comment: Interesting, that I missed that, I think I tried, but maybe my code had some errors at that point.. Thank you!